# SSRS formatting question

Tags: reporting-services

I am working in SSRS 2005.

I am trying to format numbers into two decimal places. When I add N2 in the format property of text box, all the numbers are getting two decimal values (1 will be 1.00). However, I need to format to two decimal only if it has a decimal value.

How do I achieve this? Please help..

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 1):

Try the custom format string

`#.##`

This should display the decimal places only if they are present

Comment: Thank you.... Thos who are looking for it, search with "Custom Numeric Format Strings"